# How to know when Observable or Subject has been subscribed to

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to detect when my Observable or Subject has been subscribed to.

I think there should be something like the following method in one of them:

```
public void onSubscribe(Consumer<T> listener);
```

Or even:

```
public void onSubscribe(Observer observer);
```

In the latter one, the observer which observers for another observers is being added, interesting. I think that would be usefull, I need it.

Maybe my class needs to maintain a list of subscribers from its observable, how could I achieve that? I think there isn't something like:

```
public Collection<Observer> getObservers();
```

Is there such method to get the observers? Even if there is, I would still like to be able to get notified when my Observable or Subject gets subscribed!

There actually is `onSubscribe` method but I think that one has completelly different use case, it takes `Disposable` as paramater. Can you also me tell what that one is for?

### My use case

My class needs to maintain a collection of those subscribers, I don't know is there a direct way of getting that collection from Observable of Subject, but even if there is, I still think it would be good to have `void onSubscribe(Consumer<T> c)` method simply because it provides more controll.

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? There are a number of ways of getting this information in general, but it would help if you could clarify your reasons.

Comment: question updated

Comment: `Subject.hasObservers` can tell if there is any, but other than that, there is no good reason to expose the current set of Subscribers. They rarely have usable identity and getting the hands on a bunch of them is prone to protocol violations. Why do you need such collection or notification?

Comment: Again, why? If you need to shut them down, just issue `subject.onCompleted()`. If you need to reconfigure the source, you should probably be using a `switchMap()` to select the source dynamically anyway.

Comment: okay, never mind...